# How do I use Liquid template language in a Twilio Studio "Set Variables" widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm building an SMS bot using Twilio Studio flows. I've added a [Set Variables widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#set-variables) with the following liquid code in the variable value:

```
{% capture address %}{{widgets.request_address.inbound.Body | lower | strip}}{% endcapture %}
{% if address == "yes" %}{{ flow.data.address }}{% else %}{{ widgets.request_address.inbound.Body }}{% endif %}
```

The documentation suggests this should work:

> Variables can have static values like a single number or string, or dynamic values set via the Liquid templating language.

However the code isn't being parsed and instead it's being saved as a string into the variable.

Am I missing something? Does Twilio studio just not support this despite what the documentation says?

**Update:**

I think the widget might only allow a single Liquid block. Later in the docs it says:

> This can be a number or string value, or a liquid template block like the example above.

The following code works (but is obviously not as flexible about the input)

```
{% if widgets.request_address.inbound.Body == "yes" or widgets.request_address.inbound.Body == "Yes" %}{{ flow.data.address }}{% else %}{{ widgets.request_address.inbound.Body }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyooo, Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just checked this question with our Studio team and indeed you are right. The widget accepts only a single liquid block.

In your case, what you can still do is to chain widgets together and perform formatting and logic in two steps. :)

[image: Twilio Studio flow with two chained resolve variable widgets]

What you see there is that the first widget strips whitespace and formats the input and the second one then performs the logic.

---

Hope that helps. :)